# Putting items into array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I'm working on a Python project in Visual Studio. I want to process a longer text file, this is a simplified version:

```
David Tubb
Eduardo Cordero
Sumeeth Chandrashekar
```

So for reading this file I use this code:

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    f_contents = f.read()
    print(f_contents)
```

I want to put these items into a new array that looks like that:

```
['David Tubb','Eduardo Cordero','Sumeeth Chandrashekar']
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the following code will work for this:

```
output = [] # the output list
nameFile = open('data.txt', 'r') 

for name in nameFile:
    # get rid of new line character and add it to your list
    output.append(name.rstrip('\n'))

print output

# don't forget to close the file!
nameFile.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
    result = f.read().splitlines()
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['David Tubb', 'Eduardo Cordero', 'Sumeeth Chandrashekar']
```

Answer (score 0):

The method stated by python for opening a file context is using "with open", this ensures the context will end during clean up.

[python.org-pep-0343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

```
dalist = list()
with open('data.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        dalist.append(line)
```

Additonal resource for contex handeling: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html